# create new column based on other columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

What is the best way to create a set of new columns based on two other columns? (similar to a crosstab or SQL case statement)

This works but performance is very slow on large dataframes:

```
for label in labels:
   df[label + '_amt'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['amount'] if row['product'] == label else 0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table)

```
>>> df
   amount product
0       6       b
1       3       c
2       3       a
3       7       a
4       7       a
>>> df.pivot_table(index=df.index, values='amount', 
...                columns='product', fill_value=0)
product  a  b  c
0        0  6  0
1        0  0  3
2        3  0  0
3        7  0  0
4        7  0  0
```

or,

```
>>> for label in df['product'].unique():
...     df[label + '_amt'] = (df['product'] == label) * df['amount']
... 
>>> df
   amount product  b_amt  c_amt  a_amt
0       6       b      6      0      0
1       3       c      0      3      0
2       3       a      0      0      3
3       7       a      0      0      7
4       7       a      0      0      7
```

Comment: perfect! thank-you. I went with >>> df[label + '_amt'] = (df['product'] == label) * df['amount']